# Impute and Add new calculated column with Rust DataFusion?

Tags: rust, apache-arrow-datafusion

Considering, I have a json datafile named `test_file.json` with the following content.

```
{"a": 1, "b": "hi", "c": 3}
{"a": 5, "b": null, "c": 7}
```

Here how I can read the file in With DataFrame API of DataFusion:

```rust
use datafusion::prelude::*;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> datafusion::error::Result<()> {
    let file_path = "datalayers/landing/test_file.json";
    
    let mut ctx = SessionContext::new();
    let df = ctx.read_json(file_path, NdJsonReadOptions::default()).await?;
    df.show().await?;
    Ok(())
```

I would like to do the following operation:

- Impute the null value in the b column with an empty `""` string either using fill na or case when statement
- Create a new calculated column with combining the column a and b `col("a") + col("b")`

I have tried to went through the api documentation but could not find any function like `with_column` which spark has to add a new column and also how to impute the null values.

To add two columns I can do that with column expression `col("a").add(col("c")).alias("d")` but I was curious to know if it is possible to use something like `with_column` to add a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFusion's DataFrame does not currently have a `with_column` method but I think it would be good to add it. I filed an issue for this - https://github.com/apache/arrow-datafusion/issues/2844

Until that is added, you could call https://docs.rs/datafusion/9.0.0/datafusion/dataframe/struct.DataFrame.html#method.select to select the existing columns as well as the new expression:

```
df.select(vec![col("a"), col("b"), col("c"), col("a").add(col("c")).alias("d")]);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What about imputing a column. Replacing null with a text is there any method available? The first question i have asked if you know by any chance thanks.

Comment: There is a `coalesce` function that returns the first non-null value. So perhaps `coalesce(vec![col("b"), lit("")])` ?